# Does PostgreSQL rollback when another transaction commits just before current transaction?

Tags: database, postgresql, transactions

I have a few questions so please bear with me.

1- Let's say we are trying to debit "John" and credit "Ann", we get two requests at the same time for this transaction, we first check if the balance is greater than 0 and the proceed to do the calculation and finally commit the transaction, does PostgreSQL, while using transactions, rollback to the beginning of the transaction when another transaction commits itself?

2- Do transactions on same row in PostgreSQL happen one by one? Imagine I'm `SELECT`ing from table A and then `INSERT` ing in table B, do all transactions wait to `SELECT` from A one by one? if not, is it possible to achieve this in PostgreSQL? ( I've heard that there are different kind of transactions in PostgreSQL and you can also lock a row )

3- How transactions work in PostgreSQL, do they double check themselves at the end to verify everything is the same? if yes, when you add `code logic` to add, like calculating inside your code, how does it double check itself at the end?

4- When transferring money from account A to account B, do you have to lock a row? or a transaction while checking the balance inside your code ensures that the balance is indeed the thing you got and prevents double spending?

Comment: Take a look at [Postgres transaction](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/transaction-iso.html) If that does not answer you questions, then update the question to include the parts you don't understand.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver thank you, I got all of my answers from reading the docs, just one question though, do everything happen one by one in postgresql? or is it possible to insert 2 rows at exactly same time? like 2 threads inserting in the same time

Comment: I'm not sure across all situations but here is the [libpq](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/libpq-threading.html) case and the [jdbc](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/thread.html) case. Basically AFAIK Postgres needs concurrent requests to come in on separate connections which means the ```INSERTs``` will happen in separate  snapshots and be bound by the rules in the link I posted earlier. For a better answer I would post to the [postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/list/pgsql-general/) list.

Comment: Yes, two rows can be inserted at exactly the same time.